# How to get a JavaScript Date object from the new `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Firestore recently [changed how they manage timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), and I'm unable to retrieve a `date` object from the timestamp.

How do I get a date object from the new `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```
yourFirestoreTimestamp.toDate()
```

If you look at the `Timestamp` object in the console you'll see that `.toDate()` **is a function available by default** on each `Timestamp`.

--

However, please note that when you haven't synced with Firestore yet
`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` gives nothing of value.

Only after you have synced with Firestore and the data is fetched again, the prop will be changed from `serverTimestamp` → to `Timestamp`

You'll also see much more information saved in a `Timestamp` object:

[image: preview of Timestamp in the console]

Comment: This doesn't work with return value of `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, which is not a Timestamp type object. The returned sentinel value will become a timestamp only after the document value is actual written to the document, as I've described in my answer here.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the info. I have updated my answer to include the info in your comment.

Answer (score 18):

[`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.serverTimestamp) just returns a sentinel object that you use when writing a field to a document. It indicates the server should replace it with an actual [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) object.  `serverTimestamp()` itself does not contain any date information, and you can't convert it to a date.

When you write the sentinel value to a document, and read it back out, it will become a [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) type object, which you can convert to a native Date object with its [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate) method

Answer (score 12):

At last, I could get what I need

```
new Date(firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds*1000).toLocaleDateString()
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to add a underscore (`_`) to the `seconds` key to make it work: `new Date(firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()._seconds*1000).toLocaleDateString()`

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a solution in 2022, here you go:

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

You'll need to import admin for it to work like this:

```
const admin = required("firebase-admin");
```

*Please note this only works in a node environment ie in cloud functions.

Comment: not clear that you're talking about the admin-sdk, nor where `admin` comes from. Newer devs will be very confused about this post. Also better mention this is not usable in the browser, but only in a Node environment, like cloud functions.

Comment: How to convert it to Date?