# How to manipulate Firestore extracted data to convert timestamp to date

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm trying to find a way to convert the timestamp extracted from Firestore to a regular date. Here is the code that stores the result of my query in an array :

Here is my `getActiveItemsList()` function from the `myFirestoreDatabaseService` service:

```
getActiveItemsList() {
    return this.afs.collection('GRD_active').valueChanges({idField: 'id'});
}
```

And here is the actual code where I store the data returned from Firestore :

```
this.myFirestoreDatabaseService.getActiveItemsList().subscribe(data => {
    this.displayedDataSource = data;
});
```

One of the fields of the documents in the `GRD_active` collection is a timestamp. Therefore, the data being stored in the displayedDataSource variable is the following :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4nU3.png)

How can I iterate over every document stored in the array to only reformat the date to a standard format? In other words, perform some kind of data manipulation to all the `timeEntered` and `timeCompleted` fields of every entry in the array in order to convert them to regular dates.

Thank you very much for your support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a JavaScript Date object from the new \`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416027/how-to-get-a-javascript-date-object-from-the-new-firebase-firestore-fieldvalue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just map the array with the rx map operator:

```
return this.afs.collection('GRD_active').valueChanges({idField: 'id'}).pipe(
  map(data => data.map(d => {
    d.timeEntered = new Date(d.timeEntered.seconds * 1000);
    d.timeCompleted = new Date(d.timeCompleted.seconds * 1000);
    return d;
  }))
);
```

the time is stored as a timestamp in seconds, so just multiply by 1000 to convert to ms and create a JS native Date object with that value.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you!