# How to get server timestamp in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my **Book** class , I have several fields. One of them is **additionTime**, I need to get server timestamp in this field. My class is here

```java
public class Book{

    private String bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private String authors;
    private float rating;
    private String category;
    private String thumbnail;
    private BookState bookState;
    private long additionTime;
    private String ownerID;

    public Book(){

    }

    //other getter and setters
    public FieldValue getAdditionTime(){
        return  FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    }

    @Exclude
    public long getAdditionTimeLong(){
        return additionTime;
    }

    public void setAdditionTime(long additionTime) {
        this.additionTime = additionTime;
    }


}
```

But in **additionTime** field I'm getting like **August 17, 2019 at 10:03:28 PM UTC+6**, how can I get Unix Timestamp? like 1566058638.
[image]

Comment: Convert you time into timestamp....

Comment: @Kabir thanks. How can I do that?

Comment: I just want to know...all time you get " August 17, 2019 at 10:" like format???

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("your string goes here");
long timestamp = date.getTime();

Comment: @Kabir Yes.....

Comment: Try above code...

Comment: @Kabir FieldValue.serverTimestamp() returns FieldValue. How can I get the string format? Firestore has a data type named `timestamp`, I think it automatically maps this FieldValue to `timestamp`.

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416027/how-to-get-a-javascript-date-object-from-the-new-firebase-firestore-fieldvalue/51416028

Comment: @Kabir I have some issue while adding new documents. I've added new a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578448/error-in-getting-server-timestamp-in-firestore?noredirect=1#comment101617113_57578448. Can you please check this?

Comment: Ok sure.....but i need some time...i will sure reply soon.

Comment: @Kabir After some workaround, I found that when I'm returning to the activity immediately where I showed user list app crashes, It seems like my document is added but `ServerTimestamp` expression is not replaced with the correct timestamp. When I start my app again, It shows my added document in the list. Or If I wait for a while then return my activity It shows my userlist properly.

Comment: Now i have checked your new question.crash is related totime in your model class.I just suggest one link of whole example of firestore:https://github.com/mitchtabian/FirestoreGettingStarted/tree/Inserting_Data_Start
And https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8Jl8nTU2epOY1soaCWEt7f
I hope this example help you to solve the problem.