# Error in getting server timestamp in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm trying to add a document in Cloud Firestore, but I need the server `timestamp` for adding the document. Documents are successfully added in the collection with the correct `timestamp`. I'm adding the document with an alert dialog. But when I'm returning to my activity app terminates with following errors:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ........ E/AndroidRuntime:
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.util.Date com.google.firebase.Timestamp.toDate()' on a
>   null object reference
>           at com.sasam.virtuallibrary.Models.UserLight.setTimestamp(UserLight.java:103)

For showing document's I'm using following query

```java
Query query= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Users")
                .document(user.getUid())
                .collection("friends")
                .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

My class is here

```java
public class UserLight{

    protected String name;
    protected String email;
    protected String uid;
    protected Float rating;
    protected String photoUrl;
    protected long timestamp;


    public UserLight(){

    }

    //other getters and setters

    @Exclude
    public long getTimestampLong(){
        return timestamp;
    }
    public FieldValue getTimestamp() {
        return  FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp.toDate().getTime();
    }

}
```

Code that deals with the snapshot from the query

```java
Query query= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Users")
                .document(user.getUid())
                .collection("friends")
                .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(5)
                .setPageSize(10)
                .build();

        FirestorePagingOptions<UserLight> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<UserLight>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query, config, UserLight.class)
                .build();


        mAdapter = new FirestorePagingAdapter<UserLight, ItemFriendViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ItemFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new ItemFriendViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rc_item_friend, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemFriendViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final UserLight userLight) {


                holder.txtName.setText(userLight.getName());
                GlideApp.with(holder.context).load(userLight.getPhotoUrl()).into(holder.avata);

                holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(FriendListActivity.this,FinalChatActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Friend", (Serializable) userLight);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                switch (state) {
                    case LOADING_INITIAL:
                    case LOADING_MORE:
                        // Do your loading animation
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        break;

                    case LOADED:
                        // Stop Animation
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case FINISHED:
                        //Reached end of Data set
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        retry();
                        break;
                }
            }


            @Override
            protected void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                super.onError(e);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mAdapter.refresh();
            }
        });
```

Document's after insertion
[image]

Comment: What's the code that deals with the snapshot from the query?  What exactly do the documents look like that get added?

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm using `FirestorePagingAdapter`.  I've edited my question.. Could you please check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is the fact that the type of your timestamp field inside your `UserLight` class dosn't match the type of your `timestamp` property in the database. See, in your `UserLight` class the timestamp field is of type `long`, which is basically a number while in the database is of type `Date` or `Timestamp`. Please note that both must match.

Because the correct way of holding dates in Cloud Firestore is to use the `Date` or `Timestamp` class, to solve this, simply change type of your timestamp field in your model class to be `Date`, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [ServerTimestamp is always null on Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-always-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027#48475027)

Comment: sometimes app terminates with following error        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query. You are trying to start or end a query using a document for which the field 'additionTime' is an uncommitted server timestamp. (Since the value of this field is unknown, you cannot start/end a query with it.)

Comment: That's sounds as another issue. So please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.