# How to use toDate() on Firestore.FieldValue.Timestamp?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm trying to populate a table from a firestore database which has field value timestamp data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJCi4.png]

with the following code for web:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const attendanceCollection = firebase.firestore().collection("attendance");

var lastIndex = 0;

function getData() {
    var htmls = [];
    attendanceCollection.get().then(querySnapshot => {    
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

            console.log(`${doc.id}`);
            console.log(`${(doc.data().GENERALASSEMBLY)}`)

            htmls.unshift('<tr>\
                <td>'+ `${doc.id}` +'</td>\
                <td class="message" style=" text-overflow: ellipsis">'+ `${(doc.data().GENERALASSEMBLY)}` +'</td>\
                <td style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">'+ `${doc.id}` +'</td>\
            </tr>');
        });
        $('#tbody').html(htmls);
    $("#submitUser").removeClass('desabled');
    });

};
```

which returns this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvsvM.png]

I've found some references but never actually helped me solve what I'm trying to make:

[How to get a JavaScript Date object from the new `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416027/how-to-get-a-javascript-date-object-from-the-new-firebase-firestore-fieldvalue)

[How do I convert a Firestore date/Timestamp to a JS Date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date)

how do I implement the toDate() in my code above? can you give me samples of using toDate() on converting firestore timestamps to date/string?

Comment: Did you try calling `toDate()` on `doc.data().GENERALASSEMBLY`?

Comment: i did. it returns an error
https://i.imgur.com/9O7r2tm.png

Comment: what do you get from the console log of doc.data().GENERALASSEMBLY ? Is it an object with second and nanosecond properties?

Comment: @chrismclarke yes, as seen at the 2nd photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call `toDate()` on the `GENERALASSEMBLY` field to get its value as a date. And since the field will initially be `null` when the first event fires, you also need to detect if `GENERALASSEMBLY` is `null` first.

```
${(doc.data().GENERALASSEMBLY ? doc.data().GENERALASSEMBLY.toDate() : "-unknown-")}
```

Comment: thanks! that worked, may I know what is the : "-uknown-" for?

Comment: It's just what to print when there's no date. Yo can replace it with whatever works for your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the library date-fns remember that it is unix time so
`fromUnixTime(GENERALASSEMBLY.seconds)`

then you can just use the `format` and parse the fromUnixTime

`format(fromUnixTime(GENERALASSEMBLY.seconds))`