# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_delegate}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_delegate}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

**This is the object**

```
const post = [
{
  id: 1,
name: "Farish Jamal",
description: "Web Developer",
time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
message: "This is forat",
photoUrl: "",
timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
},
{
  id: 6,
name: "Farish Jamal",
description: "Web Developer",
time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
message: "This is forat",
photoUrl: "",
timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
},]
```

**This is where i am fetching the data**

```
<div className='feed__post'>
    {post.map(({id, name, description, message, photoUrl, timestamp }) =>(
        <Post 
        key={id}
        name={name}
        description={description}
        message={message}
        photoUrl={photoUrl}
        time={timestamp}
        />
    ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp value `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is returning (what is being considered) an object and the `time` prop is not being processed properly by your `<Post>` component.

Does the error go away when you remove this `time={timestamp}`

```
<div className='feed__post'>
    {post.map(({id, name, description, message, photoUrl, timestamp }) =>(
        <Post 
        key={id}
        name={name}
        description={description}
        message={message}
        photoUrl={photoUrl}
        />
    ))}
    </div>
```

I'm not 100% on exactly the best way to process the object returned from `serverTimestamp()` but I'm referring to this post suggesting:

`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp().toDate()` which will give you a JS `Date` object, which you should be able to process into a string with `.toLocaleTimeString()`

[How to get a JavaScript Date object from the new `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416027/how-to-get-a-javascript-date-object-from-the-new-firebase-firestore-fieldvalue)

`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp().toDate().toLocaleTimeString()`

Answer (score 0):

all elements is inside in one object and you need to check the length first...

```
<div className='feed__post'>
    {(post.length > 0) && post.map(item =>(
        <Post 
          key={item.id}
          name={item.name}
          description={item.description}
          message={item.message}
          photoUrl={item.photoUrl}
          time={item.timestamp}/>
    ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should pass any of objects in your object array in map function:

```
<div className='feed__post'>
    {post.map(item =>(
        <Post 
        key={item.id}
        name={item.name}
        description={item.description}
        message={item.message}
        photoUrl={item.photoUrl}
        time={item.timestamp}/>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: No it is still not working

Comment: you should check time and timestamp property of Post object